# Firewall not allowing DNS resolution

Tags: firewall

I have the following network on the firewall

```
Infrastructure - 192.168.10.0/24
Gateway 192.168.10.1 (firewall interface 1)
DNS Server 192.168.10.2

HostsA - 192.168.20.0/24
Gateway 192.168.20.1 (firewall interface 2)
Client 192.168.20.10 (infrastructure1)
```

I had 1 rule to allow any protocol through the interface [In rule] on both interface 1 and interface 2, the client is able to ping the DNS server however when the client sends a DNS resolution query it fails to work.

So I added another [In rule] to allow TCP/UDP from one network to another yet the client in the LAN is unable to get to have DNS resolved. Clearly I'm getting confused with the in and out rule.

[HostA network In Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykPCF.png)

[Infrastructure network In Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdtoN.png)

Any thoughts what is not in order..

Comment: Which firewall ? What are your DNS servers ?

Comment: OPNSense firewall, I only have 1 local DNS server 192.168.10.2 residing in the Infrastructure Network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the infrastructure rule is wrong:

If the source is `HostA` and the destination `Infrastructure` then the direction from the perspective of the `Infrastructure` interface should be `out`, not `in`.

**solution, copied from a comment**

> This issue is resolved, I had to create both in and out rule on each interface, and now DNS resolution works fine.

Comment: You mean for the HostA interface it should be in rule, and for the Infrastructure it should be out rule. I'm understanding in and out rule from the perspective of the firewall.

Comment: @tryllz I do not know this firewall. But that combination does not make sense IMHO. Shall that allow the reply packets?

Comment: I have 1 rule per interface that allows all IPv4 packets as the in rule and this rule works. Then I had another rule per interface which was also in rule with TCP/UDP protocol and had DNS as the source and destination port, this clearly did not work. Now I'm confused if I have to have 1 In rule and 1 out rule per interface to allow traffic in and out of the interface..

Comment: @tryllz Can you check on the DNS server whether the request packets arrive there?

Comment: How do I do that, if I remove the firewall, the DNS resolution works fine. YOu mean going through live logging ?! I could only once see the HostsA udp packet in the live logging and didn ot see it again not sure what to make of it..

Comment: @tryllz I assumed that you have superuser privilege on the DNS server if you have admin access to the firewall... Is there any system (except for the firewall) in the `infrastructure` network on which you are `root`?

Comment: No, there is just a DNS Server. I do have admin access to the DNS Server..

Comment: This issue is resolved, I had to create both in and out rule on each interface, and now DNS resolution works fine.